# Capture strings from several sets of quotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

been looking for a straight answer to this but not found anything within SO or wider searching that answers this simple question:

I have a string of quoted values, ip addresses in this case, that I want to extract individually to use as values elsewhere. I am intending to do this with sed and regex.  The string format is like this:

```
"10.10.10.101","10.10.10.102","10.10.10.103"
```

I can capture the values between all quotes using regex such as:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Question is how do I select each group separately so I can use them?

i.e.:

```
value1 = 10.10.10.101  
value2 = 10.10.10.102  
value3 = 10.10.10.103
```

I assume that I need three expressions but I cannot find how to select a specific occurance.

Apologies if its obvious but I have spent a while searching and testing with no luck...

Comment: A simple pattern like `[0-9.]+` can be used to get those values.

Comment: But how would I be able to select the second address for instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565489/multiple-matches-in-a-string-using-regex-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `bash`:

```
$ str="10.10.10.101","10.10.10.102","10.10.10.103"
$ IFS="," arr=($str)
$ echo ${arr[1]}
10.10.10.102
```

Comment: Many thanks **sat** - this was exactly what I was looking for!  Have done similar in the past but for some reason not looked at it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P` you can use match reset:

```
s="10.10.10.101","10.10.10.102","10.10.10.103"
arr=($(grep -oP '(^|,)"\K[^"]*' <<< "$s"))

# check array content
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="10.10.10.101" [1]="10.10.10.102" [2]="10.10.10.103")'
```

If your `grep` doesn't support `-P` (PCRE) flag then use:

```
arr=($(grep -Eo '[.[:digit:]]+' <<< "$s"))
```

Here is an `awk` command that should work for BSD awk as well:

```
awk -F '"(,")?' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i++) print $i}' <<< "$s"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU awk, you can use `FPAT` to set the pattern for each field:

```
awk -v FPAT='[0-9.]+' '{ print $1 }' <<<'"10.10.10.101","10.10.10.102","10.10.10.103"'
```

Substitute `$1` for `$2` or `$3` to print whichever value you want.

Since your fields don't contain spaces, you could use a similar method to read the values into an array:

```
read -ra ips < <(awk -v FPAT='[0-9.]+' '{ $1 = $1 }1' <<<'"10.10.10.101","10.10.10.102","10.10.10.103"')
```

Here, `$1 = $1` makes awk reformat each line, so that the fields are printed with spaces in between.