# Multiple regex matches in one string in bash

Tags: bash

I have variable

```
test="PlayLists: 00001.mpls 01:32:39 [12 chapters] 00005.mpls 00:19:37 [4 chapters] 00003.mpls 00:08:56 [1 chapters] 00004.mpls 00:00:39 [1 chapters] 00006.mpls 00:00:29 [2 chapters] 00007.mpls 00:00:25 [2 chapters] 00000.mpls 00:00:23 [1 chapters]"
```

I tried with:

```
chapters=$([[ $test =~ ((([0-9]+) chapters)+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
echo $chapters
```

But it returns only `12 chatpters`, I want to get

```
12 chapters
4 chapters
1 chapters
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple matches in a string using regex in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565489/multiple-matches-in-a-string-using-regex-in-bash)

Comment: If you don't need a pure-bash solution I'd simply use `grep -Eo '[0-9]+ chapters'` ([try it here](https://ideone.com/SyXqia)).

Comment: @Aaron it was example output, I edited post to add ...

Comment: @SnakeEyes yeah I saw that, thank you for updating your question. Are the grep solution or the linked Q/A satisfactory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following example for a pure bash solution.

Example script:

```
# cat foo.sh
shopt -s extglob
var='[12 chapters][13 chapters][14 chapters]'
while [[ $var =~ ([0-9]+ chapters) ]]; do
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    var=${var#*+([0-9]) chapters}
done
```

The result:

```
# bash foo.sh
12 chapters
13 chapters
14 chapters
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a pure-bash solution, I would simply use the following `grep` invocation :

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+ chapters'
```

The regex matches a number followed by "chapters", the `-E` flag enables Extended Regular Expressions so we don't need to use the anticated Basic Regular Expression regex flavour, and the `-o` flag makes `grep` output each match alone on a single line rather than full lines that contain at least one match.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/hU4f0h).